# C# tree node show expand option even if node has no children

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show the expand option against a tree node even if the node has no children.  Is this possible?

(The expand option being the little plus sign in a box to the left of the node.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your purpose is to dynamically load children nodes when expanding the best solution is to add a fake child nodes to all the leaf nodes. Then replace the fake node with real ones when needed.

Comment: That's the plan.  I could do this but I wanted to check for the option first.

Answer (score -1):

Try it with property TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand = true; - this is ideal for dynamically created trees and it adds plus sign icon also to node with no children.

Comment: That property does not exist in WinForms.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry this is not a direct answer to your question, but I do feel it is relevant.

Why would you want to do this?  It is confusing for the user.

(I have just been through exactly the same process in another environment and user feedback was "This item is broken and won't let me see what's underneath like the other ones do").

In short, I would recommend evaluating the requirement carefully before you proceed.

Comment: Data must be retrieved from a database.  My options are to load each node ahead so that I do not need to set this option or to only load during expand event.